# SQL: There is already an object named X in the database

Tags: sql, debugging

This is my entire code so far

```
select Region
    into #C
    from ResearchDB.dbo.tC
    where Tier=0
```

But I already get an error:

```
There is already an object named '#C' in the database.
```

Now if I comment the line " into #C" out, it works perfectly. Whats going on??

Comment: If this is a temp table you probably ran the query already once and need to drop it before your run it again

Comment: To drop it, at the end of the code do I just add the statements: DROP TABLE #C, DROP TABLE #D, etc.. for all the temp tables Ive created?

Comment: Yes. They will also automatically be dropped when you exit the session

Comment: you have to `DROP` before you `insert`

Comment: This isn't MySQL - can you remove the tag

Comment: Long term, probably.  Short term, you likely have to drop the tables with some independent code.

Answer (score 0):

I use two options: 1 (quick but temporary) - Just hit the **Change Connection** button in SSMS and reconnect without changing any of the details. This will re-establish your connections dropping your temporary tables in the process. Don't forget to reselect your database as it will default to Master or whatever your default database has been set as.
2. I have a SP that drops all temp tables for your current session ONLY and I add this line
`EXEC dbf_DropTempTables`
at the top of each piece of code I use that creates temp tables that I made need to rerun multiple times whilst troubleshooting. Here is the SP for reference:

```
`CREATE PROCEDURE dbf_DropTempTables
AS
-- drop all #temp tables for current session
begin
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(60),
    @name VARCHAR(60)
DECLARE dtt CURSOR
    FOR SELECT  SUBSTRING(t.name, 1, CHARINDEX('___', t.name) - 1)
        FROM    tempdb.sys.tables AS t
        WHERE   t.name LIKE '#%[_][_][_]%'
                AND t.[object_id] = OBJECT_ID('tempdb..' + SUBSTRING(t.name, 1, CHARINDEX('___', t.name) - 1))
open dtt
fetch next from dtt into @name
while @@fetch_status <> -1
    BEGIN
        SELECT  @sql = 'DROP TABLE ' + @name
                EXEC ( @sql )
                fetch next from dtt into @name
    END
CLOSE dtt
deallocate dtt
END`
```